# For which $\alpha$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a}$ converge (simply and absolutely)?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am studying the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a}$. Moreover, I'm trying to find for which values of $a$ the sum converges simply and absolutely.

*I posted an answer below* of what I thought to be a correct solution. Thanks to the comments, several mistakes where pointed out.

The open problems right now are the following:

1. **Does the sum converge simply for a > 0?**
2. **Does the sum converge absolutely?**

As far as **1.** is concerned:

I supported that the sum is decreasing but this is not the case since:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^a+1}}{(n+1)^a}}{\frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^a+1}}{\sqrt{n^a+1}} \frac{n^a}{(n+1)^a} = \\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^{a/2}\sqrt{1+\frac1{(n+1)^a}}}{n^{a/2}\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^a}}} \frac{n^a}{(n+1)^a} = 1 \text{ for a>1 }$$

Therefore alternate series test doesn't seem to apply because leibniz criteria are not satisfied. Therefore, the test is inconclusive.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{n^a+1}\approx n^{a/2}$

Comment: @Venun I upvoted your answer and reversed the -1 downvote on your question because your answer showed good work.  In the future however: (1) please don't post a question naked : see this link : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question. (2) If you subsequently discover insights that you wish to share, please edit your original question to include these (new) insights.  One way of doing this is to add an **addendum** to your query.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for the insights. I make some edits right now.

Comment: @Veriun A possible exception re adding subsequent insights:  the overall goal is to improve readability of the webpage as a whole.  If your query is long-winded (e.g. you showed lots of detail) &/or your answer is long-winded, then it would make sense to post your subsequent insights as an *answer*, rather than an addendum to your query.  This way, you would be minimizing your query's "long-windedness".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a}$$

*Note that: $\sqrt{n^a+1} \approx n^{\frac{a}{2}}$ for $n>>$.*

**Theorem**

> If a sum converges absolutely then it converges simply.

Let $a_n= \left| (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a} \right| \text{ and } b_n = \frac1{n^{\frac{a}{2}}}$

From the limit comparison test:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{a_n}{b_n} \right| \approx \lim_{n\to\infty} \left| (-1)^n \frac{\frac{n^{\frac{a}{2}}}{n^a}}{\frac1{n^{\frac{a}{2}}}} \right| = k = 1 \quad 0 < k < +\infty $$

Therefore $a_n, b_n$ have the same behavior.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^{\frac{a}{2}}}= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      converges & a>2 \\
      diverges, & a \leq 2\\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

Thus,

$$
\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|(-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a} \right|= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      converges & a>2 \\
      diverges, & a \leq 2\\
\end{array} 
\right.
}$$

At last, simple convergence also applies due to the absolute convergence theorem.

---

P.S: *Thanks to everybody in the comments of the post and my other answer who helped me figure this out*

Answer (score 2):

**This answer has mistakes**

Here is what I've done so far:

---

**Convergence (Simple)**

We can re-write $a_n$ as $$a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^a}}}{n^{\frac{a}{2}}} $$

Hence the limit is:

$$ 
\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^a}}}{n^{\frac{a}{2}}} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0, & a > 0\\
      \sqrt{2}, & a = 0 \\
      \infty, & a < 0\\
\end{array} 
\right. 
 $$

Therefore by the divergence test, we know that the sum diverges $\forall a\leq 0$
As far as $a > 0$ is concerned we can see that

- $a_n > 0$
- $ a_n \searrow $:  **This is wrong.**
- $ \lim a_n = 0$

therefore the Leibnitz criteria are satisfied and the series converge **simply** only $\forall a > 0$

---

**Absolute Convergence**

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| (-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a} \right| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a} \quad(1)$$

1. Let $a\leq1$:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\sqrt{n^a+1}}{n^a} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n^a}  = + \infty$$

$\quad$therefore from the *direct comparison test* the sum **doesn't converge absolutely** for $a\leq1$

2. Let $a > 1:$

$\quad$ and let $b_n = \sqrt{n^a+1}$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^a} = 0$$

Then by the *limit comparison test* if $b_n$ converges then $a_n$ converges. Therefore $a_n$ converges  $\forall a>1)$

---

To sum up:

- The sum converges simply $\forall a>0$
- The sum converges absolutely $\forall a>1$

Comment: Excuse me, but why did you put up a question and answer it yourself ?

Comment: If you're looking for points , it's the question that will get points if others like it. Maybe you'll get points for your answers as well.

Comment: If you intended to put up what you've worked out so far, you may **edit your question** (not answer it yourself).

Comment: @Spectre Have you read https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?

Comment: @Spectre I don't care about points, I was asking a legitimate question and ended-up answering it while asking. Therefore, I shared with the community this answer

Comment: Oh.... GR8 ! You made it... I haven't read that part you referred to.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Comment: BTW, are you sure that the solution is correct ?

Comment: @Spectre Great! It seems alright to me, I wouldn't take a bet though.

Comment: Ok then , keep it up !

Comment: Several mistakes in there. In the part about simple convergence, for the limit, the first-case condition should be $a > 0$ instead of $a \geqslant 0$. After that, you wrote "... diverges $\forall a \geqslant 0$ As far as $a \leqslant 0$ is concerned ...". That should be "diverges for all $a \leqslant 0$, as far as $a > 0$ is concerned". These are probably just typos. For the limit determination, you give the wrong value for $a = 0$, then it's $\sqrt{2}$, not $1$. For the monotonicity of $a_n$, I think it's worth spending a couple of words on it.

Comment: The part about absolute convergence is wrong. Take another look, maybe use some explicit values for $a$.

Comment: Does it really converges absolutely when, for example , $a=2$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I edited the typos etc, I'm taking a loot at the rest.

Comment: @Gary It seems that it doesn't. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E2%2B1%7D%7D%7Bn%5E2%7D

Comment: @Veriun Of course it does not, the terms behave like $1/n$ for large $n$. (Use the hint given by the user Integrand!)

Comment: Thank you @Gary

Comment: @Gary It doesn't converge absolutely for n=2 but it does for larger n (sse https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%5E1000%2B1%7D%7D%7Bn%5E1000%7D)

Comment: The absolute value of the terms behave like $\frac{1}{{n^{a /2} }}$. Thus, it converges absolutely iff $a>2$.